# Rails 6: ActiveStorage::Blob needs to define a :file_attachment association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have just gone through the first few steps of upgrading from `5.2.3` to `6.1.0.alpha`

One of the errors I am seeing is related to ActiveStorage

```
     NotImplementedError:
       In order to correctly type cast Import.id, ActiveStorage::Blob needs to define a :file_attachment association.
```

Model:

```
class Import < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  ...
```

Controller:

```
import.file.attach(io: File.open(file_path(:new_file)), filename: "file-#{import_timestamp}.csv",  content_type: "text/csv")
```

I went through the upgrade guide and there are changes to how we add [multiple attachments](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-storage-assignment-behavior-change)

I didn't see anything different on the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v6.0.0/activestorage)

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38340 this error is related to this issue